# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library' which I've never added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I've been developing a .NET Web Application that connects with a SharePoint Online instance. Everything was going well until I suddenly started getting the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is a file or assembly that I have never added into the project. I've only added the following SharePoint packages via NUGET

- JohnHolliday.Caml.Net.SharePoint
- SharePoint.Client
- SharePoint.Client.Runtime
- SharePoint.Client.Search

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Installed SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK which includes the following

```
Microsoft.Office.Client.Education.dll
Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy.dll
Microsoft.Office.Client.TranslationServices.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Applications.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll
```

Unfortunately, no Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.

**UPDATE**

Finally resolved the issue. There was a SharePoint.dll in the bin folder of the project that once deleted, the project was able to run as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Some of libraries you added, such as `SharePoint.Client` are dependant on `Microsoft.SharePoint.Library`

Installing Sharepoint client components should remove that error. Download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

Comment: Good shout @Nino. Downloaded and installed SharePoint client components. Unfortunately the error is still showing.

Comment: @SeanDooley check in assembly (just navigate to c:\windows\assembly) if you have those libraries (and  right versions),

Comment: Unable to locate Microsoft.SharePoint.Library in c:\windows\assembly